# How to call a function from within a class? error is "X object has no attribute Y"

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, gtk3, pygtk

I'm a hobbyist programmer so I apologise if this seems a simple question.

When I click on a button a function is called.  The function though doesn't appear to have the info it needs to complete properly.

I've tried various things including sending the CodeBox object but they have their own errors when attempting.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import uuid


class ListBoxWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Client Diary Cash Drawer Client")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)


        # a bunch of interface elements setup here for Gtk to display properly

        # uid text box
        codeBox = Gtk.Entry()
        codeBox.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
        codeBox.set_editable(False)
        codeBox.set_size_request(300, 30)
        hbox.pack_end(codeBox, False, True, 0)
        UuidResult = uuid.uuid4()  # create a new uuid
        codeBox.set_text(str(UuidResult))
        listbox.add(row)


        # uid new button
        codeCreateButton = Gtk.Button()
        codeCreateButton.set_label("Create New Code")
        codeCreateButton.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
        codeCreateButton.connect("clicked", self.on_button_create_uuid_clicked)
        hbox.pack_end(codeCreateButton, False, True, 0)
        listbox.add(row)

    # create a new UUID 
    def on_button_create_uuid_clicked(self, widget):
        UuidResult = uuid.uuid4()  # create a new uuid
        self.codeBox.set_text(str(UuidResult))
        print(str(UuidResult))
```

I would expect a new UUID to be added into the codeBox but I get the following error `AttributeError: 'ListBoxWindow' object has no attribute 'codeBox'`

The line it's referring to is `self.codeBox.set_text(str(UuidResult))` in the function `on_button_create_uuid_clicked`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: You're are getting a error message because your are not declaring `codeBox` as instance variable, so `codeBox` is a local variable of the `__init__` function.
Change `codeBox` to `self.codeBox` to make it an instance variable. This will make it 
accessible from `on_button_create_uuid_clicked`.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.  Makes perfect sense now.  Much appreciate your help